# magento 2.3.4 cannot call methods on tabs prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'activate'

Tags: review, product-page, magento2.3.4

In Magento 2.3.4 product page when click review text or reviews and not going to **review form** or **Customer review**

**Before it's working fine in Magento 2.2.4**

and it's an error coming from the below core file in this function

> /vendor/magento/module-review/view/frontend/web/js/process-reviews.js

```
$(function () {
    $('.product-info-main .reviews-actions a').click(function (event) {
        var anchor, addReviewBlock;

        event.preventDefault();
        anchor = $(this).attr('href').replace(/^.*?(#|$)/, '');
        addReviewBlock = $('#' + anchor);

        if (addReviewBlock.length) {
            $('.product.data.items [data-role="content"]').each(function (index) { //eslint-disable-line
                if (this.id == 'reviews') { //eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
                    $('.product.data.items').tabs('activate', index);
                }
            });
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: addReviewBlock.offset().top - 50
            }, 300);
        }

    });
});
```

[image]

**I checked but I can't find proper solution 

Does anyone know about this issue?**

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: did you use require? show your full code.

Comment: @SohelRana this is default magento file 
/vendor/magento/module-review/view/frontend/web/js/process-reviews.js

Comment: Replace this line

$('.product.data.items').tabs('activate', index);

with

$('.product.data.items').tabs().tabs('activate', index);

Comment: Have you checked in browser? Your JS code is updated or not

Comment: are you using any custom theme?

Comment: @KishorThummar yes i am using this theme , http://magento2.flytheme.net/themes/sm_topmart/french

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104739/discussion-between-kishor-thummar-and-rakesh-donga).

Comment: Is your issue resolved?

Comment: any update what's in the chat is the core 2.3.4 file dont see what the changes are

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this one. The issue may be resolved by putting the below code into the `details.phtml` of `Magento_Catalog` module.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery','jquery/ui'], function($) {
    //Change the below class if not matching
        $("div.product.data.items").tabs();
    });
</script>
```

Vendor Path - `<magento-root>/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/details.phtml`

For theme - `<magento-root>/app/design/frontend/Vendor/ThemeName/Magento_Catalog/templates/ product/view/details.phtml`

**Note:** Copy `details.phtml` file from vendor path if not present in the respective theme directory.

Clear the cache if prompted.

This is purely workaround and worked for me very well in **2.3.4** instance.

Comment: thank you for answer ,yes it is working fine  for go to review form but not working in like 2 reviews and not going in 2 reviews

Comment: please check it screenshot https://prnt.sc/r7zohn

Comment: @RakeshDonga it's should work. Do u find any console err? Check `<a class="action view">` `#href` value and look for the tab value is it there or not. 
or else it maybe theme level issue.

Comment: no any error in console and i am usng `sm/topmart` theme

Comment: thanks. the issue was occurred after upgrading to Magento 2.3.4 with the Porto theme. Just adding 'jquery/ui' in details.phtml's script and works fine :)

Comment: Did anyone found a solution to this issue @RakeshDonga?

Comment: @sandip Add Your Review works not if you click on the (number of )review

Comment: @jibingeorge check new code is reflected or not. or try to play in browser console whether it works or not. that will help you to resolve further.

Comment: there is no error on the console to see any error

Comment: @jibingeorge it's not like to see any error but play with the jquery its self.   
 type  `jQuery("div.product.data.items").tabs();` in the console and so on.. the solution which I have added is a workaround. it may differ from site to site.

Comment: @RakeshDonga, i have already process-review.js updated. but still this issue there.

Comment: @sandip I did all the steps not luck !

Comment: facing this error: "Uncaught Error: no such method 'activate' for tabs widget instance"

Comment: @HafizArslan check full detail in this [discussion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104739/discussion-between-kishor-thummar-and-rakesh-donga)

Comment: @sandip yes, I have checked.try both solution. but facing this error 
"Uncaught Error: no such method 'activate' for tabs widget instance"
if I remove the solution script form detail.phtml then face  this error "cannot call methods on tabs prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'activate'"

Comment: Thanks @sandip, Its working for me...

Answer (score 16):

In Magento 2.3.3, Magento split the `jquery/ui` module into smaller parts. See https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/22995. Code should not depend on the big `jquery/ui` module anymore, but on specific modules like `jquery-ui-modules/modulename`. This improves the performance.

However, many older extensions or older custom code still depends on the big `jquery/ui` module. If there is such a dependency, the file `lib/web/jquery/compat.js` is included, which loads all jQuery UI modules. It also explicitly loads the module `jquery-ui-modules/tabs`. Normally, Magento uses its own tab implementation `mage/tabs` and does **not** use `jquery-ui-modules/tabs`. However, if `jquery-ui-modules/tabs` is loaded after `mage/tabs` you will get the error you mentioned. To reproduce this, you can open a [product page on a demo shop](http://demoshops.splendid-internet.de/magento/demoshop-magento2-daily/argus-all-weather-tank.html), open the console and execute `require(['jquery/ui'], function(){})`. When you do this and you click the review link, you will get the mentioned error.

So most probably, one of your themes / extensions / custom code also requires `jquery/ui`, which leads to the error. To fix this and to improve the performance of your page, you should get rid of that dependency.

If you cannot get rid of the dependency right away, because it e.g. comes from a third party module, another workaround is to map the `jquery-ui-modules/tabs` module to the `mage/tabs` module in your `requirejs-config.js`:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        "*": {
            // if someone depends on jquery/ui, jquery/compat is loaded
            // jquery/compat loads jquery-ui-modules/tabs
            // if jquery-ui-modules/tabs is loaded after mage/tabs, the tabs function is mapped to the wrong widget
            // (to the jquery widget and not to the Magento widget)
            // then, it is not possible to call methods on the tabs
            // this mapping fixes this issue, because jquery-ui-modules/tabs is not loaded any more
            "jquery-ui-modules/tabs": "mage/tabs"
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Simon ,  nice answer with great explanation and it works thanks !

Comment: Thans @Simon This worked for me on 2.3.4

Comment: This worked perfectly for 2.3.3. Just had to compile, manually clear pub/static/* folder, set static files and flush caches. The answer of sandip caused some errors with tabs on product page.

Answer (score 1):

> **Try This**

```
    $(function () {
        $('.product-info-main .reviews-actions a').click(function (event) {
            var anchor, addReviewBlock;

            event.preventDefault();
            anchor = $(this).attr('href').replace(/^.*?(#|$)/, '');
            addReviewBlock = $('.block.review-add .block-content #' + anchor);

            if (addReviewBlock.length) {
                $('.product.data.items [data-role="content"]').each(function (index) { //eslint-disable-line
                    if (this.id == 'reviews') { //eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
                        $('.product.data.items').tabs('activate', index);
                    }
                });
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: addReviewBlock.offset().top - 50
                }, 300);
            }

        });
    });
```